# How to fix Laravel Old value htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given?

Tags: laravel-5

The "select" element is multiple select element. I am trying to get the old values and select the options selected during the form submissions.

```
 <select class="form-control w-50" name="keywords[]" id="keywords" multiple="multiple">
 </select>
```

I am using Select2 for this element. Data is populated from remote source.

In blade

```
{{ old ('keywords') }}
```

raises the error message that says "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given".

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is `{{ var }}` will try to escape `var` with PHP's [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function, and the function accepts only strings. Here `old('keywords')` is returning an array.

I don't know what data you should provide to Select2, but I'm guessing `@foreach` will work for you:

```
@foreach (old('keywords') as $keyword)
    <li>{{ $keyword }}</li>
@endforeach
```